# jqGrid for poor and greedy people :-S

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid

So I'm using jQuery Scrollable script , but it works only for IE and FF engines and it's not so good... 
I can't find any other solution :(

But I can find [jQuery Grid plugin for PHP](http://www.trirand.com/blog/)
and ... jqGrid for ASP (what I want) 
the very big trouble is [300$](http://www.trirand.net/licensing.aspx) :(

[here](http://www.secondpersonplural.ca/jqgriddocs/index.htm) is very confusing for me php/mysql example , I need asp/mssql
how to use free jQuery grid in ASP.NET ? :)

maybe there is some realized ways or Ajax ways ?

btw I also will not buy this awesome ajax rad controls :(

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is [some code that I wrote for jqgrid 3.5 beta](http://skysanders.net/code/jQGridWS/default.aspx) that makes things a little easier. I have not updated it since the beta. You can give it a try with the current version and let me know if it works and if not I will update it.

Comment: ahm... how to install it :-S ? What is Salient.jQGridWS.Site.dll ? ASP Element or there is libraries ?..

Comment: the download link points http://jqgridws.googlecode.com/files/jqgridws.rar . I just downloaded it and followed my own directions to create the database and modify the connection string and it works. still. lol. good luck. again, it is using 3.5 beta. should work with current. if not let me know.

Comment: @nCdy: yes, there are serverside libraries and a service endpoint to serve data to your grid. The demo application has configured so you can see how to manage it in your project.

Comment: noways :( I can't understand how to work with it ...                 <div class="ui-widget-content grid-container ui-helper-clearfix">
                    <table id="grid-table">
                    </table>
                    <div id="grid-pager" class="scroll ui-helper">
                    </div>
                </div> ... how do I load sql data here ? I'm new in web dev ^_

Comment: @nCdy: you are using jquery, that is just jquery-ui. You don't need to use it if you don't want. just get rid of the class attributes. is really not as complicated as it might seem.

Comment: @nCdy: I am sorry, but I took the time to create a working sample project to explain exactly that. The rest is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

The jqGrid client-side (javascript) is licensed with dual GPL & MIT open-source licenses, so it is essentially free. Demos are here (against PHP backend, but any backend will work)

http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

The ASP.NET and PHP versions have commercial licenses and are demoed here
here:
http://www.trirand.net/demo.aspx

So just pick what you need. If you need free, go with the client-side.

Cheers,
Rumen Stankov
Trirand Inc
(makers of jqGrid)